# draw from binomial with changing probability

Tags: r, matlab

I want to draw only one number from binomial many times. Each draw corresponding to a specific probability (draw from Bernoulli with different probability). Please avoid loop.

```
y<-c(1:10)
p<- dpois(y,2)  #probability vector

#not working below

rbinom(1,1,p) #only return one value
```

Update:
 I used  Jim M's  `z=vapply(p,function(z){rbinom(1,1,z)},as.integer(1L))` The same codes except for the Bernoulli part, Matlab is 67s but R takes 520s.

Comment: Key assumptions of the Binomial distribution include a fixed number of independent trials with a constant probability of success.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this?

```
as.numeric(runif(length(p)) < p)
```

Take n random variables from uniform distribution where n is equal to the length of probability distribution: `length(p)`. Compare each value with each probability and return 1 if the value is smaller than the probability ( `as.numeric` converts `TRUE/FALSE` to `1/0`). Also, this is a lot faster than using vapply on my machine:

```
y <- 1:1000
p <- dpois(y, 2)

rBernoulli <- function(p){
    vapply(p, function(x) rbinom(1, 1, x), as.integer(1L))
}

rBernoulli2 <- function(p){
    var(as.numeric(runif(length(p)) < p))
}

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(rBernoulli(p), rBernoulli2(p))
## Unit: microseconds
##            expr      min       lq      mean    median       uq      max neval
##   rBernoulli(p) 2110.307 2197.771 2699.7286 2245.7425 2413.532 6966.376   100
##  rBernoulli2(p)   66.045   70.062   91.8782   93.9355  103.083  186.086   100
```

Comment: Why is your uniform draw given the probability condition  Bernoulli?

Comment: @Phdaml Shouldn't taking a value from uniform distribution and comparing it to a success probability to return 1 be equivalent to drawing a number from Bernoulli given an equal success probability as the former? I'm using this approach to make things faster.

Answer (score 4):

It turns out `rbinom` could do similar tasks too when p is a vector. It is slightly slower than the accepted answer.

```
 rbinom(length(p),size=1,p)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since p is a vector of probabilities, we can generate a Bernouilli random draw for each
probability in turn by applying the same function to each probability in turn. Using vapply constrains the type the return value, in this case, an integer.

```
set.seed(12345)

y <- 1:10
p <- dpois(y, 2)

rBernoulli <- vapply(p, function(x) rbinom(1, 1, x), as.integer(1L))
```